# Thread-safety and delegates with generated numbers

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, thread-safety

In the main class, loops generate numbers (0~100), and when its generated number is > 20, its value is passed to the thread where it simulates some work with this number. Meanwhile, while this number is being processed, other generated numbers > 20 must be skipped.

Is this code OK? I am not sure if I'm doing something bad or not. In fact it seems to be working fine, but I don't know if it can be written by that way or even "better.".

```
class Program
{
    delegate void SetNumberDelegate(int number);
    delegate bool IsBusyDelegate();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        ProcessingClass processClass = new ProcessingClass();
        SetNumberDelegate setNum = new SetNumberDelegate(processClass.setNumber);
        IsBusyDelegate isBusy = new IsBusyDelegate(processClass.isBusy);
        Thread processThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(processClass.processNumbers));
        processThread.Start();
        int num;
        int count = 0;
        while (count++ < 100)
        {
            num = rnd.Next(0, 100);
            Console.WriteLine("Generated number {0}", num);
            if (num > 20)
            {
                if (!isBusy())
                {
                    setNum(num);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread BUSY! Skipping number:{0}", num);
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        processThread.Abort();
        processThread.Join();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
class ProcessingClass
{
    private volatile bool busy;
    private volatile int number;

    public ProcessingClass()
    {
        busy = false;
        number = -1;
    }

    public bool isBusy()
    {
        return busy;
    }

    public void setNumber(int num)
    {
        number = num;
    }

    public void processNumbers()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (number > -1 && !busy)
            {
                busy = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Processing number:{0}", number);
                // simulate some work with number e.g. computing and storing to db
                Thread.Sleep(500); 
                Console.WriteLine("Done");
                number = -1;
                busy = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no synchronisation here and so all access to the thread's state is subject to data races. It is comprehensively not threadsafe.

From what I can tell all you need is to implement a producer/consumer pattern. Do this with a blocking queue. Please don't use busy loops. They burn CPU cycles and are horribly non-performant.

Comment: any short code sample, please?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `BackgroundWorker`?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int count = 0, num;

    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);

    while(count++ < 100)
    {
        num = rnd.Next(0, 100)
        Console.WriteLine("Generated number {0}", num);
        if(num > 20)
        {
            if(!bw.IsBusy)
                bw.RunWorkerAsync(); //calls bw_DoWork function
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Thread BUSY! Skipping number:{0}", num);
        }   
    }
    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //do something with number in background
    }
}
```

If you wish to abort, call `bw.CancelWorkerAsync()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do what you expected to do.
Enqueue all Numbers greater than 20 if no number is in the queue of the thread.
Please leave a comment if you wanted to do something else, i would be glad giving you the right examples.

```
class Program
{
    delegate void SetNumberDelegate (int number);

    delegate bool IsBusyDelegate ();

    static void Main (string[] args) {
        Random rnd = new Random ();
        ProcessingClass processClass = new ProcessingClass ();

        ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent (false);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (processClass.ProcessNumbers, resetEvent);

        int num;
        int count = 0;
        while (count++ < 100) {
            num = rnd.Next (0, 100);
            Console.WriteLine ("Generated number {0}", num);

            if (num > 20) {
                if (!processClass.IsBusy) {
                    processClass.Enqueue (num);
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Thread BUSY! Skipping number:{0}", num);
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (1);
        }
        resetEvent.WaitOne ();
        Console.ReadKey ();
    }
}

class ProcessingClass
{
    readonly Queue  numberQueue = Queue.Synchronized (new Queue ());
    bool aborting = false;
    object abortingLock = new object ();

    public bool Aborting {
        get {
            lock (abortingLock) {
                return aborting;
            }
        }
        set {
            lock (abortingLock) {
                aborting = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsBusy {
        get {
            return numberQueue.Count > 0;
        }
    }

    public void Abort () {
        Aborting = true;
    }

    public void Enqueue (int num) {
        lock (numberQueue) {
            numberQueue.Enqueue (num);
            Monitor.PulseAll (numberQueue);
        }

    }

    public int Dequeue () {
        lock (numberQueue) {
            if (numberQueue.Count == 0)
                Monitor.Wait (numberQueue); 
            return (int)numberQueue.Dequeue ();
        }

    }

    public void ProcessNumbers (object threadContext) {
        //please create an own class for this!
        ManualResetEvent resetEvent = (ManualResetEvent)threadContext;
        //
        StartProcessingNumbers ();
        resetEvent.Set ();

    }

    private void StartProcessingNumbers () {
        while (!aborting) {
            int num = Dequeue ();
            Console.WriteLine ("Processing number:{0}", num);
            // simulate some work with number e.g. computing and storing to db
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (200); 
            Console.WriteLine ("Done");             
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT thread-safe at all... for this sort of thing (Producer/Consumer) use BlockingCollection - see MSDN reference including code sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx